# Flutter Transparent Container and BoxShadow

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am stuck on this. I am trying to learn Flutter. While I was doing my custom project I hit this wall. I know this can be solved with AppBar, maybe. I want to learn how to draw custom shadow or at least alter BoxShadow.

When I try to add a box shadow to my row which wrapped with container I get this result;

[shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCVpw.jpg)

Code looks like this;

```
class HeaderContents extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(offset: Offset(0, 2), blurRadius: 5)]),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
```

As you can guess I am just trying to get elevation result to the bottom. Thanks everyone.

Comment: that should had work or the problem is your container parent widget. your container might have a min width.Maybe try adding your desired width on your container. double.infinity or some width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is just my retardness on assigning color. On main file I assigned both dark and bright colors for testing out dark/light mode functionality.

Changing this,
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor

to this,
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `SpreaRadius` and increase the `OffsetY`. Change all the value to get the desired need.

```
      BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.1),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 20,
              offset: Offset(
                  0, 10), // changes position of shadow
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: I get a complete white result from this with extremely blurred shadow which is expected from the code. Am I wrong?

Comment: I just put random value. Change them as you need. But it will work.